# Web frameworks without monkey patching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, web-frameworks, monkeypatching

Web frameworks such as Django and Rails rely on monkey patching to enable support for plugins.

Are there web frameworks, using Python or Ruby, that support plugins without having to resort to monkey patching? And how would it be possible to architect the code to support plugins without monkey patching, especially if one moved to a statically typed language?

Comment: *Rails::Plugin is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 4.0. Instead of adding plugins to vendor/plugins use gems or bundler with path or git dependencies.* (from changelog).

Comment: Do you have any idea what you are talking about? What is a 'django plugin' - there's no such concept in the django docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I question your definitions of "monkey-patching" and "plugins".

Django *very much so* supports "plugins", though it calls them "packages" or "modules". Here's a site that exists only to list available packages for Django:

http://www.djangopackages.com/

I know nothing about Rails, but I'd bet my house it has similar things.